# Отправка на почту сводки о действиях на сайте

Tags: php

Скрипт по отправке на почту данных о выполнении действий на сайте. Чтобы быть точнее, у меня на сайте есть форма для заполнения, и вот когда посетитель ее заполняет и нажимает на кнопку «отправить заявку», нужно чтобы мне на почту или аську было оповещение, что пришла заявка. Как такое сделать?

Comment: Как мне кажется такое невозможно!

Comment: @Prikol95, ...

Comment: @Prikol95, если не знаете, то не говорите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял, то вам надо чтобы пользователь с сайта мог отправить вам письмо на почтовый ящик. Например, "Обратная связь". То вам надо работать с функцией `mail()`.

**Добавлено из комментария**.

@androni, необходимо сделать так. Функцию `mail()` поместить в скрипт добавления данных в БД. Вот отрывок моего кода:

```
if ($record == "") {
    $error = "Нет текста<br /><br />";
} else
    $query = "INSERT INTO guestbook VALUES" . "('$user', '$record', '$ava', '$date')";
$headers = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=\"windows-1251\"\n";
$headers .= "From: admin@localhost\n";
$subject = "TEST MESSAGE";
$body    = "TEST";
$to      = "admin@localhost";
mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
if (!mysql_query($query))
    echo "<br><br>Ошибка вставки: $query " . $error;
```

Надеюсь, по нему поймете, что при выполнении условия отправляются данные в БД и на почту. Иначе выдаст ошибку.

Comment: нет! посититель в заявке заполняет свои днные. и попадает в мою базу данных! И вот мне надо чтобы мне пришло оповещение что появился новый клиент! А не форма обратной связи (это у меня есть)

Comment: А какая разница? Все равно делается через функцию `mail()`. Исходя из вашего случая, я считаю, что лучше сделать так. Пользователь отправляет данные в БД и в это же время отправляется письмо к вам на почту.

Comment: Совершенно согласен с DeN230494

Comment: А как это правильно сделать? Извините, просто я новичек в этом.

Comment: mail() часто отключается хостерами для безопасности...

Comment: Если я вставлю вот это:

`<?php 
mail("joecool@example.com", "My Subject", "Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3"); 
?> `
То отправляется, когда заходят на страницу. А что надо, чтобы отправлялось во время отправки в БД.

Comment: у меня не отключен!

Comment: Перенесено в ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Простейшая форма отправки сообщения вам на почту, дальше допилите сами под ваши нужды:

```
<form method="post" action=""> 
Имя отправителя:<br />
<input type="text" name="user" size="50"><br />
E-mail отправителя:<br />
<input type="text" name="user_email" size="50"><br />
Тема сообщения:<br />
<input type="text" name="subject" size="50"> <br />
Текст сообщения:<br />
<textarea name="text" cols="80" rows="10" ></textarea><br />
<input type="submit" name="send_mail" value="Отправить">
</form>
<?php

if (isset($_POST['send_mail']) && isset($_POST['subject']) && isset($_POST['text']) &&
    isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['user_email'])) {

    /* получатели */
    $to = "ВАШ E-MAIL";

    /* тема/subject */
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $text = $_POST['text'];
    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $user_email = $_POST['user_email'];

    /* сообщение */
    $message = '
<html>
<head>
 <title>' . $subject . '</title>
</head>
<body>' . $text . '
</body>
</html>';

    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=Windows-1251\r\n";

    $headers .= "From: " . $user . "<" . $user_email . ">\r\n";

    if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {

        echo "<b>Сообщение отправлено!</b>";

    } else {

        echo "Ошибка отправки!";

    }

} else {

    echo "<font color=red><b>Не заполненны текстовые поля!!!</b></font>";

}

?>
```

Comment: Можно было просто сказать, как можно сделать...и все. Да, кстати, на некоторых хостингах PHP - функция "mail" не валидна, то есть отключена для безопасности. Если оно так и есть, то ваш код не сработает...

Comment: А как это правильно сделать? извените, просто я новичек в этом!!

Comment: если я вставлю вот это : <?php mail("joecool@example.com", "My Subject", "Line 1nLine 2nLine 3"); ?> То отправляется когда заходят на страницу. А что надо что бы отправлялось во время отправки в БД.

Comment: @z668, здесь вам CRON поможет.

Comment: @Asen а почему CRON?  
@androni сразу после строчки с отправкой в БД поместите строчку с отправкой письма.

Comment: @Asen на всех нормальных платных хостингах функция mail включена по умолчанию, исключение - бесплатные шаражные хостинги которые вдобавок вешают свою рекламу на сайт пользователя.
@Asen при чем тут CRON? чем он мне поможет?

Comment: Всем спасибо! Получил хороший ответ от DeN230494 ему отдельное спасибо!!! Все получилось. после небольших доделок все работает как хотел!!

Comment: Не за что, рад был помочь.